# Solid box using nested for loops

Tags: java, nested-loops

```
public void makeBox()
{
    output = "";

    for (int i = size; i > 0; i--) {
        for (int j = size; j > 0; j--) {
            output += "*";
        }
        for (int k = 1; k <= size; k++) {
            output += "#";
        }
        output += "\n";
    }
}
```

size is the variable for number of columns

when size = 4, the output should look like this:

```
****#
***##
**###
*####
```

Comment: So... what's your question?

Comment: What is wrong in the code? (Except that it is horribly inefficient, use `StringBuilder`?)

Comment: You should try using your `i` variable inside of your inner loops.

Comment: I have to use for loops

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to **use `i`**.

Your inner loop does the same thing independent of the value of `i`.

You need to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add "*" size - row times.

You want to add "#" row+1 times.

Where row is the current row number starting count at 0.

You should use StringBuilder because it's less costly than concatenation.
See [StringBuilder vs String concatenation in toString() in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java)

Result would look like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
     for(int j = 0; j < size - i; j++) sb.append("*");
     for(int k = 0; k < i+1; k++) sb.append("#");
     sb.append("\n");
}
```

Now you can do what you want with the result. To get it in string format:

```
String result = sb.toString();
```

Comment: To be pedantic, use System.lineSeparator() instead of "\n".